High variability in reading speeds of feather with arrow::read_feather in R
I have a 12GB feather file that I read into R with
data_df <- arrow::read_feather('fname.feather')

It often takes around 2 seconds. But sometimes it can take around 60 seconds. I have noticed it being this slow in RStudio IDE and Positron IDE, but also in the R console in the system terminal, so it does appear to be the R interface that is the issue.
I can not find a way to reproduce it but have experienced it repeatedly for many months.
Does anyone know of any reason why things must take 2 seconds usually, but be painfully slow sometimes, when reading feather files?
I have 96GB of RAM and most of it is free when I read in the feather file.

My system is Arch Linux
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7900X 12-Core, 96GB DDR5 RAM.
R is 4.4.2; arrow package is 17.0.0.1
RStudio 2024.09.1.394-1 , Positron 2024.11.0.116-1

